# jpql select query with where clause does not differentiate non english characters

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql

i'm using hibernate jpa 3.6.7. i have a table that stores country names and i have a country named "Türkiye".  i wrote a query like this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM EntityCountry c WHERE c.countryName = :country").setParameter("country", "turkiye");
long result = (long)query.getSingleResult();
```

result returns 1. i am using mysql with utf8 collation and i can insert turkish characters with jpa successfully. but this query does not differentiate non-english characters and lower-upper case. please help

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has its own rules regarding case-sensitivity. Comparisons between strings are case-insensitive and uses a collation by default. To make it case insensitive the query or the column itself must use a binary collation.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html for additional information.

Comment: thank you again JB Nizet. i changed both database and table's collation to utf8_bin and restarted mysql but still there is no difference between 'u' and 'ü' according to mysql. note: actually i don't care about case-insensitive comparison